# Google drive api-File uploaded but not listed

Tags: php, web-services, google-api, google-drive-api

I am new to google drive api.. I am working on uploading files from my server to google drive.

In my gmail account I have

1. created a Service Account, download keys and uploaded to server
2. Provided access to Drive Api and SDK Api.
3. Added a Controller to communicate with google as:

   ```
       set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT .DS. "vendors");
       require_once('Google/Client/Google_Client.php');
       require_once('Googl
   ```

e/Client/contrib/Google_DriveService.php');

```
    define('CLIENT_ID','my_client_here....');
    define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME','my_account_name here');
    define('KEY_FILE',VENDORS.'Google/Client/key/privatekey.p12');  // what i was availed by google.       

    if(is_file(KEY_FILE)){
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
        $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
          array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
          $key)
     );


     $service = new Google_DriveService($client);


            $file = new Google_DriveFile();
            $file->setTitle('Any sample file title');
            $file->setDescription('An experiment to upload text file via server to server');
            $file->setMimeType('text/plain');

            $data = "Lorem ipsum is a dummy text";

            $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
                  'data' => $data,
                  'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
                ));


            print_r($createdFile);
```

Now the output of this is as follows:

```
[kind] => drive#file
[id] => 0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ
[etag] => "11QSOvUX6KZKZVB6nCB3GloLTJQ/MTM5MDU2MzUwNTU2OQ"
[selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ
[webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ&export=download
[alternateLink] => https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ/edit?usp=drivesdk
[iconLink] => https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_text_list.png
[title] => Any sample file title
[mimeType] => text/plain
[description] => An experiment to upload text file via server to server
[labels] => Array
    (
        [starred] => 
        [hidden] => 
        [trashed] => 
        [restricted] => 
        [viewed] => 1
    )

[createdDate] => 2014-01-24T11:38:25.679Z
[modifiedDate] => 2014-01-24T11:38:25.569Z
[modifiedByMeDate] => 2014-01-24T11:38:25.569Z
[lastViewedByMeDate] => 2014-01-24T11:38:25.569Z
[parents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [kind] => drive#parentReference
                [id] => 0AONwgyCI2GQEUk9PVA
                [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ/parents/0AONwgyCI2GQEUk9PVA
                [parentLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AONwgyCI2GQEUk9PVA
                [isRoot] => 1
            )

    )
[downloadUrl] => https://doc-04-60-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/lptjog45u94o44tbsu1586vcuinvv74h/mlvse3i90c59eb4q6ggg7d4c6v6q4hfd/1390557600000/03476129820556261866/03476129820556261866/0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true
    [userPermission] => Array
        (
            [kind] => drive#permission
            [etag] => "11QSOvUX6KZKZVB6nCB3GloLTJQ/-HVXFUAxHplEpHWK6MSWEcIX7d8"
            [id] => me
            [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-NwgyCI2GQENkswOHVNcVl2aDQ/permissions/me
            [role] => owner
            [type] => user
        )

    [originalFilename] => Any sample file title
    [fileExtension] => 
    [md5Checksum] => 2c06987d6ae9cfcd7060c68f4356231a
    [fileSize] => 31
    [quotaBytesUsed] => 31
    [ownerNames] => Array
        (
            [0] => sdsdsdswrwew@developer.myemail.com
        )

    [owners] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => drive#user
                    [displayName] => dsdadasd3@developer.myemail.com
                    [isAuthenticatedUser] => 1
                    [permissionId] => 03476129820556261866
                )

        )

    [lastModifyingUserName] => 89989989889@developer.myemailid.com
    [lastModifyingUser] => Array
        (
            [kind] => drive#user
            [displayName] => my_display_name
            [isAuthenticatedUser] => 1
            [permissionId] => 03476129820556261866
        )

    [editable] => 1
    [copyable] => 1
    [writersCanShare] => 1
    [shared] => 
    [appDataContents] =>
```

..............

Now the main problem is that the files upload via this is not listing in my google drive files list but if I query for the availale files in my account I get only the file list uploaded via this api and not the one I created manually in the google drive interface.

See my code to get file list..

```
   .....................
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
            $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
            $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
              SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
              array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
              $key)
            );

            $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    ....................

            $files = $service->files->listFiles();
```

Now Questions:

1. Why do the files not listed in my google drive list.
2. Why the service account I created in google console is treated as like a different user. eg file list are different than original users and orignal user file are not listed in api listed files.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong, also let me know if what I am trying to achieve is possible or not. I have created a Service Account rather than `Client ID for web application` because the script will run automatically without any user interface.

Please suggest....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why do the files not listed in my google drive list?**

Because they don't belong to you. They belong to the service account.

**Why the service account I created in google console is treated as like a different user.**

Because that is what a service account, ie. it's own user.

If you want uploaded files to be in your own Drive contents, then you need to use your own account credentials to the Drive SDK. This does not need to involve user interaction. You simply need to acquire a refresh token one time, then use that subsequently to generate the access token for Drive.

Comment: Hi pinoyyid ... is there any way i can share or transffer these files to other user account via any api... and where can i view application files

Comment: Yes they can be shared like any other file. What do you mean by "application files" ?

Comment: means the app id I created in google console.. thanks

Comment: right now i am following this as you said... https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server... do you think this will work for me

Comment: Yes it can. Be aware that the documentation always assumes that the user will be authing his own Drive account. Your situation is that you are using your own account, so the user has no authorization to do. You will of course somehow need to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateFile ($service, $fileId, $newTitle, $newDescription, $newMimeType, $text) {
    try {
        // First retrieve the file from the API.
        $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

        // File's new metadata.
        $file->setName($newTitle);
        $file->setDescription($newDescription);
        $file->setMimeType($newMimeType);

        // File's new content.
        $additionalParams = array(
            'data' => $text,
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        );

        // Send the request to the API.
        $updatedFile = $service->files->update($fileId, $file, $additionalParams);
        return $updatedFile;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```