# Google Drive Api with Service Account C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, google-api, google-drive-api

I've programmed to my API has a service account in my application, it works fine, all connection, upload, download and delete stuff, but when I used to use User Service, all files goes to my personal drive, now it goes somewhere, I think it goes to Google Cloud Platform...
The question is, I don't have any account over there, because you need to pay to use that, so, does anyone knows where all these files goes?

Here the code I'm using to make a connection call

```
    public static DriveService Connection(string path, string username, string p12Path)
    {

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12Path, "XXXXXXXX", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("g service account")
            {
                Scopes = Scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });

        return service;
    }
```

---

And here the method I'm using to upload a file.

```
    [Authorize]
    public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File Upload(DriveService service, string uploadFile, string name)
    {

        var body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        body.Name = name;
        body.MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile);

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFile);
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(body, stream, GetMimeType(uploadFile));
        request.Upload();
        return request.ResponseBody;
    }
```

---

So, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29009874/5832311), the code is the same and there is no difference if you are using Oauth2 or a service account. You may check with this [tutorial](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive). Also based from this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21332749/5832311), if you want uploaded files to be in your own Drive contents, then you need to use your own account credentials to the Drive SDK. This does not need to involve user interaction. You simply need to acquire a refresh token one time, then use that subsequently to generate the access token for Drive. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot m8, I was worried about it. You really help me :D