# Google Drive API - File upload in own account withoug signing - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, google-api-php-client

I have a website, in which user fill forms and when they click on save, I add that details to database and creating a csv of that data.

I don't want to save that csv in my server, instead I would like to save it to my own google drive.

So, I can't show users a login popup, as I don't want to upload in their account, How can I upload that files in my account without disturbing user (In background)?

I tried many solutions out on Internet, like "simple-file-upload, service-account, etc."

I think Service account service can help me here, but not getting any proper solution out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would consult the documentation for the API https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads. Look at the PHP examples.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you use a free **@gmail.com** account, this won't be possible. In order to achieve this, you need to have a [**G Suite**](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/) account because you will need to enable [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority). Since you did not post any code about the solution you have tried, then I am not able to tell exactly how you want to achieve this; Nevertheless, here is an example of an upload of a CSV file.

```
<?php session_start(); 

require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; //include php client library

// define service account credentials
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service_account_credentials.json');

//set the required scopes
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

$client= new Google_Client(); // Create client object
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); // Set service account credentials
$client->addScope($scopes); //Set scopes to client object
$client->setSubject("email@domain.com"); // impersonate user

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // define service to be rquested

//Create new drive file metadata
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
  array('name' => 'PeopleList.csv') //set file name
);

//Construct CSV data
$content = array(
  array("Name", "Age", "Gender"), // CSV Header or First row
  array("John Doe", "27", "Male"), // Row 2
  array("Alex Wright", "24", "Female"), // Row 3
  array("Elli Smith", "25", "Female") // Row 4
);

$fileName = "CSV_Test.csv"; // define temp csv file name
$csvFile = fopen($fileName, 'w'); // open file to write on it

//save content to csv file
foreach ($content as $row) {
  fputcsv($csvFile, $row);
}

fclose($csvFile); // close csv file

$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName); //extract csv file data

//upload csv to drive
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
  'data' => $csvData,
  'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
  'uploadType' => 'multipart'
  )
);

//delete temp csv file
unlink($fileName);

print_r($file);

?>
```

Comment: Hello @Morfinismo
Thank you for your answer.

I had created Gsuite account, Tried mine and your code (mixup)
Now, I am not getting any error, And getting File Id in return.

But, Where can I see uploaded file?
In my Gsuite Account's Drive It does not display.

Please read here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332267/google-drive-api-file-uploaded-but-not-listed?rq=1

It also say we can't see files uploaded from service based account.
Then what is the meaning of using it?

Can you please help?

Comment: @vatsalshah The reason is not being displayed in your G Suite account is because you are not impersonating the user. Make sure you put your email address on this line `$client->setSubject("youremail@yourdomain.com");`. If you do not impersonate the user, you will upload the file to the service account instead to yours. That should fix the problem.